# Magento security patches (SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533) installation remainder is still coming in admin panel after installation

Tags: magento, patch

I had download and install SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533 magento patches in my site when i got 1st remainder in admin panel. After installing i marked the notification as marked . After few days  a got another notification regarding the same issue.Why these notification notifications are coming after the installation.
  Is this because of any error in installation ?  HOw can i check patches are installed successfully

thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer explains where you can check to see if the patch is applied within your magento install: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64431

You can check if your store is still vulnerable here: https://shoplift.byte.nl/

As for the messages, they'll keep coming even with the patches installed, just mark as read.

Comment: My applied.patches.list file have following portion about these patches 

2015-04-17 13:01:27 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.13 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13_v1.patch 
2015-04-17 13:01:32 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | 

i think this installation have no errors .But i still got critical remainder from magento about installation. I got another remainder today .

Comment: Magento is going to keep sending the reminders, it doesn't matter if the patches are installed or not, it's like a newsletter/notice. They don't examine your install and then send it, they just issue the message to all installs.